# How to delete item images from the file directory related to the item in spring jpa

Tags: spring, boot

How to delete item images from the file directory related to the particular item while cascade delete is used in the relationship(ONE-TO-MANY).

Description:

-Each item has 3 images, and all the images are stored in the file directory.

-And Image file directory paths are stored in a separate table with item Id as a foreign key, and it is a one to many relationship between items and images tables.

So is there any way, like Cascade.Delete which deletes all the orphans related to that id?